# How to mock an object wrapped in a JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb, mockito

Consider the following code generated by JAXB:

```
public class CnpOnlineResponse {

    protected JAXBElement<? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup> transactionResponse;

    public JAXBElement<? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup> getTransactionResponse() {
        return transactionResponse;
    }

    public void setTransactionResponse(JAXBElement<? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup> value) {
        this.transactionResponse = value;
    }
}

public class AuthorizationResponse extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup {

}

public class ObjectFactory {

    public JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse> createAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse>(_AuthorizationResponse_QNAME, AuthorizationResponse.class, null, value);
    }
}
```

I am writing a test in which I am mocking both a CnpOnlineResponse and an AuthorizationResponse:

```
@Mock private CnpOnlineResponse mockCnpOnlineResponse;
@Mock private AuthorizationResponse mockAuthorizationResponse;

final JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse> authorization = CnpContext.getObjectFactory().createAuthorizationResponse(mockAuthorizationResponse);

when(mockCnpOnlineResponse.getTransactionResponse()).thenReturn(authorization); // <= ERROR here
```

However I am getting the following compilation error:

```
The method thenReturn(JAXBElement<capture#1-of ? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup>) in the type OngoingStubbing<JAXBElement<capture#1-of ? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup>> is not applicable for the arguments (JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse>)
```

Any help appreciated, I do not understand why it thinks the thenReturn is not being passed an object of the required type.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to test here. Why do you create an actual `JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse>` in the first place? You should be using a mock instead of calling the `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: No. I will be testing the 2 mock objects, but the getTransactionResponse() returns a JAXB wrapped object and not an AuthorizationResponse. I also tried mocking the JAXBElement, but got exactly the same error on the thenReturn().

Comment: thenReturn() is having an issue with my JAXBElement<AuthorizationResponse> even though quite clearly AuthorizationResponse extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to confuse the type inference.

Use `thenAnswer` (or shorter `then`).

```
when(mockCnpOnlineResponse.getTransactionResponse()).then(i -> authorization);
```

The `i -> authorization` is a lambda expression evaluating to an `Answer<? extends TransactionTypeWithReportGroup>` with a capture it's able to match.